# Crazy nested Excel (or VBA) statement that looks through rows of data containing ICD-10 Codes

Tags: excel, vba

I need a formula in Excel that looks through a row of data (ICD-10 codes) and checks for specific codes i.e. "Z00001", "Z139", etc. about 7 different codes and returns the code(s) contained in the ICD-10 codes in that row. It doesn't matter what position it is in (ICD 1-10), just that it is in the row. I need to find out if it is just one code or two or more of the codes and which codes they are. I think I may have to break it down into a couple of columns but not sure how to do that. Below is what I have tried but I only get whichever code is the first code the formula comes across, not all of the specific codes listed.

```
=IF(OR(COUNTIF(O2:X2, "Z9289")>0),"Z9289",IF(OR( 
COUNTIF(O2:X2,"Z0001")>0),"Z0001", IF(OR( COUNTIF(O2:X2,"Z789")>0), IF(OR( 
COUNTIF(O2:X2,"Z139")>0), "CNR"))))
```

I've even tried:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(O3:X3={"Z0001","Z139","Z789","Z7689","Z87898","Z9289"}))>0
```

Comment: you definitely need to break this up into multiple columns so you can get each function working on it's own. For example, each `COUNTIF` could go into it's own column so you ca see what they are counting (ie., `=COUNTIF(O2:X2,"Z139")` Also review how the [`IF`](https://support.office.com/article/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) function works.